# Consolidating timestamps based on a defined time difference end event and next start event to identify unique visits

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, timestamp

I would like to consolidate timestamps into "true" start_timestamp and "true" end_timestamp based on a criteria that x (in this case 8 hours) must elapse between and end_timestamp and the next start_timestamp for it to be a distinct event. Any timestamps that fail this criteria would take the overall min start_timestamp and max end_timestamp for that given range.

Suppose I have this df

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
                 start_timestamp = c("2022-04-26 23:36:00", "2022-04-27 18:29:00", "2022-04-29 11:37:00", "2022-05-02 22:29:00", "2022-05-10 10:06:00", "2022-05-12 19:57:00", "2022-04-01 12:00:00", "2022-04-04 15:35:00"),
                 end_timestamp = c("2022-04-27 12:28:00", "2022-04-29 07:00:00", "2022-05-02 13:41:00", "2022-05-10 09:00:00", "2022-05-12 15:16:00", "2022-05-15 15:12:00", "2022-04-04 11:49:00", "2022-04-07 11:42:00"))

df$start_timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$start_timestamp)
df$end_timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$end_timestamp)

> df
  id     start_timestamp       end_timestamp
1  A 2022-04-26 23:36:00 2022-04-27 12:28:00
2  A 2022-04-27 18:29:00 2022-04-29 07:00:00
3  A 2022-04-29 11:37:00 2022-05-02 13:41:00
4  A 2022-05-02 22:29:00 2022-05-10 09:00:00
5  A 2022-05-10 10:06:00 2022-05-12 15:16:00
6  A 2022-05-12 19:57:00 2022-05-15 15:12:00
7  B 2022-04-01 12:00:00 2022-04-04 11:49:00
8  B 2022-04-04 15:35:00 2022-04-07 11:42:00
```

I would like to achieve an output that looks like this:

```
> df
  id visit     start_timestamp       end_timestamp
1  A     0 2022-04-26 23:36:00 2022-05-02 13:41:00
2  A     1 2022-05-02 22:29:00 2022-05-15 15:12:00
3  B     0 2022-04-01 12:00:00 2022-04-07 11:42:00
```

I tried an approach where I used the lag of the end_timestamp to compare the time difference between that and the previous start_timestamp and then define a grouping variable of visit based on an 8 hour difference; however, as you can see that does not work for me because the visit does not carry forward to subsequent rows in the new event within that ID as you can see below.

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(start_timestamp, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(prev = lag(end_timestamp, default = min(start_timestamp)),
         time_between = difftime(start_timestamp, prev, units = "hours"))

df$visit <- ifelse(df$time_between < 8, 0, 1)

> df
  id     start_timestamp       end_timestamp                prev   time_between visit
1  A 2022-04-26 23:36:00 2022-04-27 12:28:00 2022-04-26 23:36:00 0.000000 hours     0
2  A 2022-04-27 18:29:00 2022-04-29 07:00:00 2022-04-27 12:28:00 6.016667 hours     0
3  A 2022-04-29 11:37:00 2022-05-02 13:41:00 2022-04-29 07:00:00 4.616667 hours     0
4  A 2022-05-02 22:29:00 2022-05-10 09:00:00 2022-05-02 13:41:00 8.800000 hours     1
5  A 2022-05-10 10:06:00 2022-05-12 15:16:00 2022-05-10 09:00:00 1.100000 hours     0
6  A 2022-05-12 19:57:00 2022-05-15 15:12:00 2022-05-12 15:16:00 4.683333 hours     0
7  B 2022-04-01 12:00:00 2022-04-04 11:49:00 2022-04-01 12:00:00 0.000000 hours     0
8  B 2022-04-04 15:35:00 2022-04-07 11:42:00 2022-04-04 11:49:00 3.766667 hours     0
```

My goal in this small subset of the data would have seen rows 5 and 6 also have visit = 1 so that I could group and then take the min(start_timestamp) and max(end_timestamp) to get my true visit ranges.

Any suggestions as to how I can get to my goal output? Thanks!

Comment: You're very close to achieving your goal: use `cumsum(ifelse(time_between < 8, 0, 1))` to define visit, and summarise by visit and id :)

Comment: @Maël the problem with summarising is summarise has deprecated support for multiple row outputs! reframe would be the bet no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're wanting something like this:

```
df |>
  mutate(visit = if_else(is.na(lead(start_timestamp)), FALSE, end_timestamp - lead(start_timestamp) >= 8)) |>
  mutate(start_timestamp = min(start_timestamp), end_timestamp = max(end_timestamp), .by = c(id, visit)) |> 
  distinct()
```